# See list of stock trades for day

Tags: united-states, stocks

Is there is a place where I can see all trades for certain ticker for a given date? I am pretty sure I have seen something like this, but I can't find it. It was even showing the names of the people from the company that were trading the company stock.

Comment: Are you referring to the insider trade records?  I'm not aware of an orderbook that identifies the individual who made the order...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see all the (millions) of trades per day for a US stock only if you purchase that data from the individual exchanges (NYSE, NASDAQ, ARCA, ...), from a commercial market data aggregator (Bloomberg, Axioma, ...), or from the [Consolidated Tape Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_Tape_Association).  In **none** of that data will you ever find identifying information for the traders.

What you are recalling regarding the names of "people from the company" trading company stock is related to SEC regulations stating that people with significant ownership of company stock and/or controlling positions on the company board of directors must publicize (most of) their trades in that stock.  That information can usually be found on the company's investor relations website, or through the SEC website.

Comment: I found the place I've previously seen: http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/insideractions